# Python how to limit the score (Code doesn't work after adding the if avg== etc

Tags: python

I am trying to find scores from only 7 judges and to have the numbers between 1-10 only, what is the problem with my code I am an newbie trying to self teach myself:)

So what I'm asking is how to limt the input to have to be 7 inputs per name and to limt the user input to 1-10 for numbers.

```
import statistics#Importing mean
def check_continue(): #defining check_continue (checking if the user wants to enter more name/athletes
    response = input('Would you like to enter a another athletes? [y/n] ') #Asking the user if they want another name added to the list
    if response == 'n': #if n, ends the loop
        return False
    elif response == 'y': # if y, continues the loop
        return True
    else:
        print('Please select a correct answer [y/n]') #making sure the awsener is valid
        return check_continue() #calling check continue
while(True):
    name = input('Please enter a athletes name: ') #asking for an athletes name
    if name == (""):
        print ("try again")
        continue
    else:
        try:
            print("Enter the judges scores with space inbetween each score") #asking for scores
            avg = [float(i) for i in input().split( )] #spliting the scores so the user only needs to put a space for each score
        except ValueError:
                continue
                print("Please enter scores only in numbers")
                scores = '' .join(avg)
                print("please only enter number")
                if scores ==("") or scores <=0 or scores >=10:
                    print("Please enter a score between 1-10")
                    continue
                else:   
                    print("_______________________________________________________________________________")
                    print("Athlete's name ",name) #Printing athletes name
                    print("Scores ", avg) #printing athletes scores
                    avg.remove(max(avg)) #removing the highest score
                    avg.remove(min(avg)) #removing the lowest score
                    avgg = statistics.mean(avg) #getting the avg for the final score
                    print("Final Result: " +
                          str(round(avgg, 2))) #printing and rounding the fianl socre
        if not check_continue():
            break
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

1. After reading input scores from judges, make sure that len(input.split()) == 7 to match first criteria.
2. Once you have the list of scores, just have a check that for each score, 1 <= int(score) <= 10.

If necessary, I can provide a working code too.

```
import statistics  # Importing mean


def check_continue():  # defining check_continue (checking if the user wants to enter more name/athletes
    # Asking the user if they want another name added to the list
    response = input('Would you like to enter a another athletes? [y/n] ')
    if response == 'n':  # if n, ends the loop
        return False
    elif response == 'y':  # if y, continues the loop
        return True
    else:
        # making sure the awsener is valid
        print('Please select a correct answer [y/n]')
        return check_continue()  # calling check continue


while(True):
    # asking for an athletes name
    name = input('Please enter a athletes name: ')
    if name == (""):
        print("try again")
        continue
    else:
        scores = [float(i) for i in input('Enter the judges scores with space inbetween each score').split() if 1 <= float(i) <= 10]
        if len(scores) != 7:
            print("try again")
            continue
        print("_______________________________________________________________________________")
        print("Athlete's name ", name)  # Printing athletes name
        print("Scores ", scores)  # printing athletes scores
        scores.remove(max(scores))  # removing the highest score
        scores.remove(min(scores))  # removing the lowest score
        # getting the avg for the final score
        avg = statistics.mean(scores)
        print("Final Result: " + str(round(avg, 2)))  # printing and rounding the final score
        if not check_continue():
            break
```

This one should work. Let me know if there are any issues.

```
scores = [float(i) for i in input('Enter the judges scores with space inbetween each score').split() if 1 <= float(i) <= 10]
```

This line of code only saves values between 1 and 10, thus already checking for those values. Then the number of elements is checked to be 7.
PS: Would also want to point out that in your code, nothing ever executes after the except ValueError: continue. The continue basically skips to the next iteration without running any of the next lines of code.

Comment: That would be very kind if you could provide a working code foe me to look at thank you:)

Comment: Works very well thank you, but the only problem I have now is when a non number is enter it kills the whole thing

Comment: Glad it was helpful. You can just enclose it within a try except statement in order to fix that problem. Just make sure to not add anything after the continue statement (at least not within the same scope as it will not run).

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. All checks of input you can warp before printing results with `if all():` function for length of input scores list and range of nums between 1 and 10 (see code below).

For mean calc you don't need to delete value from list. You can make sorting and then slicing of list.

`check_continue()` can be simplify. Check entering for `y` or `n` value and return `True` or `False` by cases in dict. Otherwise loop.

```
import statistics

def check_continue():
    response = input('Would you like to enter a another athletes? [y/n] ').lower()  # Format Y and N to y and n
    if response in ['y', 'n']:  # Check if response is y or n
        return {'y': True, 'n': False}[response]
    check_continue()


while True:
    name = input('Please enter a athletes name: ') #asking for an athletes name
    if name:  # Check if name not empty
        while True:  # make a loop with break at only 7 scores enter
            scores_input = input("Enter the judges scores with space inbetween each score (only 7 scores)").split(' ')
            try:
                scores = [float(s) for s in scores_input]  # sort list for extract part for avgg calc
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter scores only in numbers")
                continue
            if all([len(scores) == 7, max(scores) <= 10.0, min(scores) >= 1]):
                print("_______________________________________________________________________________")
                print(f"Athlete's name {name}") #Printing athletes name
                print(f"Scores {scores}") #printing athletes scores
                avgg = statistics.mean(sorted(scores)[1:-1]) #getting the avg for the final score
                print(f'Final result - {avgg :.2f}')
                break
            else:
                print("Please enter 7 numbers for scores between 1-10")
    if not check_continue():
        break
```